# How to scrape jsp written web pages?

Tags: selenium, jsp

I want to automate the process of getting logged in to the website https://www.fois.indianrail.gov.in/foisweb/view/GG_LoginNew.jsp?txtProj=TMS%20ZONAL&clintId=? .

I have tried referencing all the text fields in the web page.

```
driver.get('https://www.fois.indianrail.gov.in/foisweb/view/GG_LoginNew.jsp?txtProj=TMS%20ZONAL&clintId=')

pot='//*[@id="txtUserId"]'

tom=driver.find_element_by_xpath(pot)

tom.send_keys('text')

mot='//*[@id="txtPassword"]'

pot=driver.find_element_by_xpath(mot)

pot.send_keys('text')

radio_point='//*[@id="txtOptnD"]'

iiu=driver.find_element_by_xpath(radio_point)

iiu.click()

location_point='//*[@id="txtLocation"]'

mp=driver.find_element_by_xpath(location_point)

mp.send_keys('text')

submit='//*[@id="Submit"]'

sub=driver.find_elements_by_xpath

sub.click()
```

I expect the username text field to be written as text but the error is

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to
>   locate element: //*[@id="txtUserId"]

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. What did you investigate based on the error message. Also format your code in your question.

Answer (score 1):

The element you are trying to access is inside a frame. You have to switch to that frame before accessing the elements.

**Try This:**

```py
driver.get('https://www.fois.indianrail.gov.in/foisweb/view/GG_LoginNew.jsp?txtProj=TMS%20ZONAL&clintId=')

driver.switch_to.frame("frmCUMain")

driver.find_element_by_id("txtUserId").send_keys("text")

driver.find_element_by_id("txtPassword").send_keys("text")

driver.find_element_by_id("txtOptnD").click()

driver.find_element_by_id("txtLocation").send_keys("location")

driver.find_element_by_id("Submit").click()
```